# C fwrite output does not appear correctly in Matlab

Tags: c, matlab, fwrite

I have this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>


int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    int N = 4;
    int *A =  malloc( N * sizeof( *A ) );


    for ( int i = 0 ; i < N; i++ ) 
        A[ i ] = i;


    FILE * theFile;
    theFile = fopen( "theA", "wb" );
    assert( NULL != theFile );
    fwrite( A , sizeof( int ) , N , theFile );
    fclose( theFile );


    return 0;
}
```

Now , if I load the file in matlab , it shows :

```
 0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     2     0     0     0     3     0     0     0
```

If I use this code in order to read from file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>


int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    int N = 4;
    int *A = malloc( N * sizeof( *A ) );


    FILE * theFile;
    theFile = fopen( "theA", "wb" );
    assert( NULL != theFile );
    fread( A , sizeof( int ) , N , theFile );
    fclose( theFile );

     for ( int i = 0 ; i < N; i++ ) 
        printf("\nA = %d",A[ i ] );



    return 0;
}
```

it shows  :

```
A = 0
A = 0
A = 0
A = 0
```

Any explanation?

In matlab I am using:

```
 fid = fopen('theA','rb')
 A = fread(fid);
```

Comment: What were you expecting the Matlab output to look like?

Comment: @Matt McNabb:The same as in C without all the zeros?

Comment: maybe also post the matlab code you were using, along with the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the [`precision`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fread.html#inputarg_precision) parameter in Matlab, otherwise by default Matlab `fread` will read byte by byte.

> **Default:** 'uint8=>double'

My `C` is rusty but I guess the class `int` cast a 32 bits signed integer. You have to tell this information to Matlab otherwise it uses the default interpretation noted above.

So in Matlab, simply do:

```
fid = fopen('theA','rb')
A = fread(fid , 'int32' );
fclose(fid) ;
```

This will result in:

```
A =
     0
     1
     2
     3
```

Which should be your normal output (at least it is what you wrote in the file initially).

Answer (score 2):

You're opening the file for write, when you want to read:

```
theFile = fopen( "theA", "wb" );
                          ^
                          |
                         FAIL
```

Make that `"rb"`.

Of course, you *should check the return values from I/O functions*, if you did you would have learned that `fread()` failed, so the values printed don't mean anything. I/O can (and will!) fail in interesting and educational ways, always check the return values.

Comment: :Ok, I missed that!Thanks! But why when I load the file to matlab  (fopen('theA','rb')) it shows the output I have in the post?

Answer (score 2):

In 2nd part:

should be:

```
theFile = fopen( "theA", "rb" );
```

instead of:

```
theFile = fopen( "theA", "wb" );
```